# What type of tense is 'would have had'?

Tags: tense, past-perfect, subjunctives

I know how to use 'would have had', but I’m really unsure about the tense. Is it past or present tense? Is it conditional?

Comment: Syntactically, an example like "He would have had enough money" is past tense because "would" is a past tense modal auxiliary verb. The embedded subordinate clause "have had enough money" is perfect tense. Such clauses often occur in conditional constructions.

Comment: @LucianSava the link you provide does not answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

It is "conditional perfect" as you can see from a chart at https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have#Conjugation. (Click on "show".)

Comment: Conditional is not a tense, but a type of adjunct, a preposition phrase to be precise. And since the head verb in the upper matrix clause is past form "would", that would make the sentence as a whole 'past tense'.

Comment: @BillJ: "In the traditional grammatical description of some languages, including English, many Romance languages, and Greek and Latin, "tense" or the equivalent term in that language refers to a set of inflected or periphrastic verb forms that express a combination of tense, aspect, and mood." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tense%E2%80%93aspect%E2%80%93mood)

Comment: @GerardH.Pille But not in Present-day English.

Answer (score 1):

The verb phrase **would have had** (would have possessed [would have had the money], would have experienced [would have had a good time]) refers to *something  not actual in the past* (because some condition was not true).

> They would have had a picnic yesterday if it hadn't rained.

But it can be used in present non-actual contexts:

> I would have had enough money with me now if I had not forgotten my
>   wallet.
>
> I would have enough money with me now if I had not forgotten my wallet.